# "Invalid argument" when sending UDP packet, but which?

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, sendto, invalid-argument

My C++ application is sending binary data as UDP packets. The sendto() call returns EINVAL (Invalid argument), but I don't see anything wrong with the parameters I'm passing.

I did an strace of the application and here are the revelant system calls:

```
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 33
setsockopt(33, SOL_IP, IP_RECVERR, [1], 4) = 0
fcntl(33, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
bind(33, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1510), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0

sendto(33, "\2055\5\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\1\20 \0t\0c\300Ny\274B\10*\206H\206\367\r\2\5\0\200\200\331'\344\272\322\362sD\277\312\300\23\240\224\212\16\20\1\0\0\22", 55, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1510), sin_addr=inet_addr("219.132.100.190")}, 16) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

Does anybody see which parameter is invalid?

The application has recently been ported to support IPv6, but I don't know if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Does your routing table contain a valid route to that address?  What is `sizeof (sockaddr_in)` on your system?

Comment: @Ben: Yes, there is a valid route and 16 is the correct length of sockaddr_in.

Comment: Binding to 127.0.0.1 likely binds to `lo`. 219.132.100.190 is likely not an address that is valid to send data to over `lo`

Comment: This may sound weird, but try removing the call to `bind`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You bound your socket to the local address 127.1, but you are sending to a non-localhost address. I need to check, but perhaps the EINVAL means "you can't send 127.1 packets off-host."

Comment: Or equivalently, there's no route in the routing table for destination of `219.132.100.190` using interface `lo`.

Comment: He bound his *socket* to *127.0.0.1*. You don't bind local addresses.