# UdpSocket.send_to fails with "invalid argument"

Tags: sockets, udp, rust

I came across this problem while experimenting with BitTorrent tracker protocol using Rust.

This simple program that is supposed to send some data using UDP sockets is failing:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::io::net::addrinfo;
use std::io::net::ip::{Ipv4Addr, SocketAddr, IpAddr};
use std::io::net::udp::UdpSocket;

fn main() {
    let addr = SocketAddr { ip: Ipv4Addr(127, 0, 0, 1), port: 34254 };
    let mut socket = match UdpSocket::bind(addr) {
        Ok(s) => s,
        Err(e) => panic!("couldn't bind socket: {}", e),
    };

    let host_addr = "tracker.openbittorrent.com";
    let port = "80";

    let host_ips: HashSet<IpAddr> =
        addrinfo::get_host_addresses(host_addr.as_slice()).unwrap().into_iter().collect();

    for host_ip in host_ips.into_iter() {
        let socket_addr = SocketAddr {
            ip: host_ip,
            port: from_str(port).unwrap(),
        };
        println!("Sending to {}", socket_addr);
        let data: &[u8] = [0x1, 0x2, 0x3];
        println!("{}", socket.send_to(data, socket_addr));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Sending to 31.172.63.252:80
Err(invalid argument (Invalid argument))
Sending to 31.172.63.253:80
Err(invalid argument (Invalid argument))
```

Any ideas about what's going wrong?

Comment: This looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505315/invalid-argument-when-sending-udp-packet-but-which, does it help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are binding the socket to localhost (the loopback interface), and then trying to communicate through that socket to an address not on that interface. If you instead bind to `0.0.0.0`, it will succeed. This means "all ipv4 interfaces". You can bind to a more specific address if necessary.